# why do i get an error of function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int mf_option(1);
int mf_rectangle(2);
int main()
{
    int mf_option(1);
    int mf_rectangle(2);
return 0;
}
int mf_option(1)
{

    char a;
    int size = 0;
    cout << "Enter a character: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    while (size < 1 || size > 5)
        cout << "Enter a valid size from 1-5: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
}
int mf_rectangle(2)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= size; col++)
        {
            if (row > 1 && row < size && col > 1 && col < size)                 
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    for (int row = 2; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 2; col <= size; col++)
        {
            if (row > 2 && row < size && col > 2 && col < size)
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    for (int row = 3; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 3; col <= size; col++)
        {
            if (row > 3 && row < size && col > 3 && col < size)             
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    for (int row = 4; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 4; col <= size; col++)
        {
            if (row > 4 && row < size && col > 4 && col < size)                 
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    for (int row = 5; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 5; col <= size; col++)
        {
            if (row > 5 && row < size && col > 5 && col < size)
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << a;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error in lines 15 and 26.  there is also an error on line 15 that says expected ';'.  here is the error message
Error   1   error C2448: 'mf_option1' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Comment: Where are these 1s and 2s coming from?

Comment: It appears the the function defintions `int mf_option(1)` and `int mf_rectangle(2)` are malformed. It appears that parameter names should be present in the function definitions instead of the values `1` and `2`. You should supply the `1` and `2` values when calling these functions. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
int mf_option(1);
```

is a definition of the variable `mf_option`. It's type is `int` and value is `1`. It's not a declaration of a function.

Later on, you have:

```
int mf_option(1)
{
 ...
}
```

That is a syntactically invalid construct. It starts out like you are going to define a variable and ends up like you are defining a function.

Similar problem exists for `mf_rectangle`.

If I understand your intention correctly, you need to replace the lines:

```
int mf_option(1);
int mf_rectangle(2);
```

by

```
int mf_option(int arg);
int mf_rectangle(int arg);
```

Make similar changes to where you are trying to define the functions.

Comment: should we call this the invexed parse? :) The intent was to declare a function but the code actually declares a variable with initializer

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'll vote for that term :)